# Finding variance using the matrix method

Tags: statistics, covariance, variance

If the random variables $X,Y$ and $Z$ have means: $$\bar{x}=2 \;\;\; \bar{y}=-3 \;\;\; \bar{z}=4$$ and variances $$\operatorname{Var}(x)=1 \;\;\; \operatorname{Var}(Y)=5 \;\;\; \operatorname{Var}(Z)=2$$ and 
co-variance $$\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)= -2\;\;\; \operatorname{Cov}(X,Z)=-1\;\;\;\operatorname{Cov}(Y,Z)=1$$ Find

1. Mean of $W=3X-Y+2Z$
2. The variance of $W=3X-Y+2Z$ **using the matrix method**

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For a proficient interaction, please take a few minutes to learn MathJax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. Also providing the attempt that you've made would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Hint

> $$E[aX+b] = aE[X]+b$$
>     $$\operatorname{Var}[aX+bY] = \mathbf{v}^T\mathbf{M}\mathbf{v}$$ where $\mathbf{v} = \left(\begin{matrix}a\\b\end{matrix}\right)$ and $\mathbf{M}$ is the matrix of covariance defined (in the case two variables) as $$\left(\begin{matrix}\operatorname{Var}[X]&\operatorname{Cov}[X,Y]\\\operatorname{Cov}[Y,X]&\operatorname{Var}[Y]\end{matrix}\right)$$

### Solution

> The fist question is the easiest, from the linearity of the mean you can simply add together the means with their respective coefficientent given by the formula for $W$, mainly $$E[W] = E[3X-Y+2Z] = 3E[X]-E[Y]+2E[Z] = 3(2)-(-3)+2(4) = 17$$ The second, given the formula above is to be solved by simple matrix multiplication. In our case $$\mathbf{v} = \left(\begin{matrix}3\\-1\\2\end{matrix}\right)\;\;\;\mathbf{M}=\left(\begin{matrix}\operatorname{Var[X]}&\operatorname{Cov[X,Y]}&\operatorname{Cov[X,Z]}\\\operatorname{Cov[Y,X]}&\operatorname{Var[Y]}&\operatorname{Cov[Y,Z]}\\\operatorname{Cov[Z,X]}&\operatorname{Cov[Z,Y]}&\operatorname{Var[Z]}\end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix}1&-2&-1\\-2&5&1\\-1&1&2\end{matrix}\right)$$ Then we calculate the variance of $W$ as $$\operatorname{Var}[W] = \operatorname{Var}[3X-Y+2Z] = \underbrace{\left(\begin{matrix}3&-1&2\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}1&-2&-1\\-2&5&1\\-1&1&2\end{matrix}\right)}_{\text{first multiplication}}\left(\begin{matrix}3\\-1\\2\end{matrix}\right)$$ let's do first the underbraced multiplication $$\left(\begin{matrix}3&-1&2\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}1&-2&-1\\-2&5&1\\-1&1&2\end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix}3&-9&6\end{matrix}\right)$$ and now let's do the second multiplication $$\left(\begin{matrix}3&-9&6\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}3\\-1\\2\end{matrix}\right)=30$$ So in the end we have that $$\operatorname{Var}[W]=30$$

Comment: Please note that $\mathbb E(aX+b)=a\cdot \mathbb E(X)+\color{red}b$

Comment: @callculus Ops, my bad! Thank you

Comment: Is there any difference between Cov(Y,X) and Cov (X,Y) ?@DavideMorgante

Comment: No, covariance is symmetric! $$Cov[X,Y]=Cov[Y,X]$$

Comment: @DavideMorgante Thanks. So from the hint above I'm supposed to get the determinant of the matrix or? Kindly shed some light I'm new to the matrix method.

Comment: Give me a second and I'll post the complete answer with calculations

Comment: I've posted the solution. If it was what you were looking for I would Kindly appreciate that you mark my answer as accepted and give an upvote ;)

Comment: Thanks I had already found the mean to be 17 .Once again thanks @DavideMorgante

Comment: You're welcome!