# Determining variance of sum of both correlated and uncorrelated random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, covariance, variance

David Mitra had a great, simple answer to a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115518/determining-variance-from-sum-of-two-random-correlated-variables) of how to determine the variance of the sum of two correlated random variables. What if, however, I have three normally distributed random variables, only two of which are correlated with one another - how do I find the variance? My thinking is that since

> Var(A+B) = Var(A)+ Var(B)+ 2Cov(A,B)

works for two correlated variables, maybe you can just throw in a third, uncorrelated variable C getting:

> Var(A+B+C) = Var(A) + Var(B) + Var(C) + 2Cov(A,B)

Also, what if I have more variables and more of those variables are correlated? Say I have variables A, B, C, D and E and A, B and C are all correlated to one another. Would this be a possible solution:

> Var(A+B+C+D+E) = Var(A) + Var(B) + Var(C) + Var(D) + Var(E) + 2Cov(A,B)  + 2Cov(A,C) + 2Cov(B,C)

Comment: You first and third equation are right. The second equation is right if  A,C and B,C are uncorrelated.

Comment: @callculus I did mean to C is uncorrelated to the other two variables in the second equation - I'll edit that now. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Since $\mathsf {Var}(S)=\mathsf{Cov}(S,S)$ and $\mathsf{Cov}(S,T)=\mathsf{Cov}(T,S)$, and covariance is bilinear, we have that:$$\begin{align}\mathsf {Var}(A+B) & =\mathsf{Cov}(A+B,A+B)\\ &=\mathsf{Cov}(A,A)+\mathsf{Cov}(A,B)+\mathsf{Cov}(B,A)+\mathsf{Cov}(B,B) \\ &= \mathsf{Var}(A)+2\mathsf{Cov}(A,B)+\mathsf{Var}(B)\end{align}$$

Likewise, in general:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf{Var}(\sum_{i}A_i) &=\mathsf {Cov}(\sum_i A_i,\sum_j A_j)\\ &= \sum_i\sum_j\mathsf{Cov}(A_i,A_j)\\&=\sum_i\mathsf{Var}(A_i)+2\sum_{i<j}\mathsf{Cov}(A_i,A_j)\end{align}$$

And specifically:$$\begin{align}\mathsf{Var}(A+B+C) &=\mathsf {Cov}(A+B+C,A+B+C)\\&~~\vdots\\&=\mathsf{Var}(A)+\mathsf{Var}(B)+\mathsf{Var}(C)+2\mathsf{Cov}(A,B)+2\mathsf{Cov}(A,C)+2\mathsf{Cov}(B,C)\end{align}$$

And so on.   Of course, if any two variables are pairwise uncorrelated, their relevant covariance term will vanish.

Answer (score 0):

By using the formalism of the [*matrix of covariance*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix) you can easily extend to every possible case. Remember that uncorrelated variables have zero covariance so you would just have some zeros in the matrix.

I've answered a similar question on [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2867166/finding-variance-using-the-matrix-method#2867184) that maybe can shed some light on the problem!

If you have a sum of $N$ variables such as $$W = \sum_{n=1}^Na_nX_n$$ you can write the variance of $W$ in matrix formalism as $$\operatorname{Var}[W] = \mathbf{v}^T\mathbf{M}\mathbf{v}$$ where $\mathbf{v}$ is a vector containing all the $a_n$, mainly $$\mathbf{v} = \left(\begin{matrix}a_1\\a_2\\\vdots\\a_n\end{matrix}\right)$$ and the matrix $\mathbf{M}$ is the *matrix of covariance* defined as $$\left(\begin{matrix}\operatorname{Var}[X_1]&\operatorname{Cov}[X_1,X_2]&\operatorname{Cov}[X_1,X_3]&\cdots&\operatorname{Cov}[X_1,X_n]\\\operatorname{Cov}[X_2,X_1]&\operatorname{Var}[X_2]&\operatorname{Cov}[X_2,X_3]&\cdots&\operatorname{Cov}[X_2,X_n]\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\\operatorname{Cov}[X_n,X_1]&\operatorname{Cov}[X_n,X_2]&\operatorname{Cov}[X_n,X_3]&\cdots&\operatorname{Var}[X_n]\end{matrix}\right)$$ which is a symmetric matrix, because $\operatorname{Cov}[X,Y]=\operatorname{Cov}[Y,X]$ and positive semidefinite